# Import CSV with Embedded GeoJSON Geometry in ARCGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geojson, csv

I have a CSV file with an embedded GeoJSON geometry in a column.  See screen capture. I have tried some online CSV to GeoJSON conversion tools, but all cannot process a column with a GeoJSON embedded geometry in it.  Does anybody know of an online tool that can process a CSV file with an embedded GeoJSON object and turn it into a GeoJSON file or any format that ARCGIS can read?
[image]

Comment: Can easily be done with a short python script, or any other programming language. Possibly even a one-liner using `awk`.... Can you make the data available?